# Woocommerce - Want to move the product tabs below short description

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sticky-post, tabs

i've two questions. I would like to move Woocommerce-tabs underneath my short description on the right side. I found this but the accordion is not full-width.

```
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 60 );
```

I also would like to make the pictures/text sticky as in this website:

https://www.kustomdesigns.com.au/?product=mx-jersey

**my website**

//morenatural.nl/product/jojoba-olie-biologisch-koudgeperst/

I hope someone could help. Thanks already guys.

Cheers,

Henk

Answer (score 0):

I moved the tabs underneath the short description jeeej. But i would like to make it sticky. is that possible?

**Like this:**

https://www.kustomdesigns.com.au/?product=mx-jersey

Kind regards,

Henk